# why does linking two boxes not produce symmetrical results?

Tags: j, apl

Just learning J.  I'm confused by the output:

[image: box of boxes]

Since we are linking two elements, each of which is already boxed, I expected both elements to look like the first -- that is, a list of boxed boxes.

Why is only the first item a boxed box, while the second item is just a box?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is intentional and is done so that

```
   2;3;4
┌─┬─┬─┐
│2│3│4│
└─┴─┴─┘
```

instead of

```
┌─┬─────┐
│1│┌─┬─┐│
│ ││2│3││
│ │└─┴─┘│
└─┴─────┘
```

Really just convenience to make it easier to create lists of boxes. Good observation though.

A much fuller explanation can be found in Henry Rich's 'J for C programmers' http://www.jsoftware.com/help/jforc/more_verbs_for_boxes.htm#_Toc191734395

Comment: I think `(<0);(<1);<(<2)` is the way to accomplish the original idea.